# Restore default boot OS to Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, acer, chromebook, chromeos

I am having a problem with ChrUbuntu and setting the default OS back to Chrome OS. I have tried `sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 0 -S 1 /dev/sda` but all that returns is `futility failed to exec /usr/bin/old_bins/cgpt: No such file or directory`. How can I fix this? I have tried everything I know of, including trying to get `cgpt` back from the `old_bins` directory. No luck.

Comment: If the apt-get doesn't work, have a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/342343/cannot-boot-back-into-chromeos-from-chrubuntu-acer-c710-2847/350834#350834 .
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this problem myself. Fixed with `sudo apt-get install cgpt`.